# CSS Parser in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

is there any CSS parser in the CodeIgniter Framework?
If not: Where should I store my PHP file for parsing css (neat solution)? In the webroot?

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing". Just a regular `<link href=...` or *REAL* parsing of the contents?

Comment: I mean replacing (i.e. replace #url# with http://mydomain.tld)

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is displayed from the root directory (index.php) there is no need to put the url in the CSS file as you can have it relative to the root directory.

Comment: If I access my site via mydomain.tld/index.php, all works fine. But if I use mydomain.tld/controller/subsite the relative path doesn't work

Comment: The images in a CSS file are relative to the directory the CSS file is in.

Answer (score 0):

I use two solutions:

**application/controllers/one.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class One extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->helper('url'); // important!, check auto-load note
    $this->load->view('one');
  }
}

/* End of file one.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/one.php */
```

**application/views/one.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>One</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- page content -->

</body>
</html>
```

In order to auto-load the [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html):

> *If you find that you need a particular helper globally throughout your
>   application, you can tell CodeIgniter to auto-load it during system
>   initialization. This is done by opening the
>   **application/config/autoload.php** file and adding the helper to the
>   autoload array.*

This way it is not necessary to write `$this->load->helper('url');` in every controller.

The other solution is retrieving the 'base_url' item from your primary config file (**application/config/config.php**) and avoiding loading the URL helper file:

**application/controllers/two.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Two extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('two');
  }
}

/* End of file two.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/two.php */
```

**application/views/two.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Two</title>
  <!-- We retrieve the config item -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- page content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps